# Div does not expand to maximum width

Tags: css, html

I have the following css class:

```
.CtractLabel
{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align:left;
    /* width:120px; */
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #aaaaaa;
    border-right:solid 1px #aaaaaa;
    background: white url('../Images/GridHeaderBg.gif') repeat-x bottom;
}
```

On my page, I have a a div with text that is less than 150px. However, the div does not expand to 150px, but contracts around the text.
Is there a way to force the div to be precisely 150px regardless of the length of the text in the div?

Comment: The CSS snippet you provided appears to work fine in a blank document with only that definition applied to some DIVs. Can you provide more information? What browsers are you testing, and do you have any other styles that might modify the DIV as well?

Comment: What does that div's parent container look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for the width of a `div` element is `auto`, which causes it to take up all available space horisontally.

If you don't get this behaviour, there are some possible causes:

- You have made it a floating element.
- You have specified a width for it somehow, perhaps indirectly.
- You have some other element taking up space.

To see exactly what CSS applies to an element, and exactly where elements are, you can use the FireBug plugin in Firefox.