# Why doesn't this DIV expand to the width of the children

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue and wondering why my containing DIV does not expand to the width of the big table?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.blueprintcss.org/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.blueprintcss.org/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
      <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.blueprintcss.org/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->
      <style type="text/css">
         div.add-padding {
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: red;
         }
         table {
            background-color: blue;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="add-padding">
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr><td>FOO</td></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr><td>BAR</td></tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <td>SEQ</td>
                  <td>ID</td>
                  <td>ParentID</td>
                  <td>Case Category</td>
                  <td>Case #</td>
                  <td>Case ID</td>
                  <td>Account Code</td>
                  <td>Account Code ID</td>
                  <td>Trans Date</td>
                  <td>Person ID</td>
                  <td>FullName</td>
                  <td>Suffix</td>
                  <td>PayeeID</td>
                  <td>OperatorID</td>
                  <td>Notes</td>
                  <td>CheckID</td>
                  <td>ReceiptID</td>
                  <td>Void</td>
                  <td>TransCategoryID</td>
                  <td>CaseFull</td>
                  <td>TransTypeID</td>
                  <td>Xfer To</td>
                  <td>Ref #</td>
                  <td>View Amount</td>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
                  <td>foo_bar</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504863/div-does-not-expand-to-maximum-width

Comment: @Alex: Not a dup (of that question at least) my div does in fact expand to the width of the viewport, just not to the containing elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is what you want, but try this:

- You should add `<!DOCTYPE html>` (the HTML5 doctype) as your very first line (you must do this to escape [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and help to ensure consistent rendering between different browsers).
- Add `float: left` to `div.add-padding`.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/emodi4)

Comment: That fixes the problem in both Chrome (so I assume all webkit based browsers) and Firefox which are the only two I care about for this application.   Can you explain WHY floating left fixes it?  As you pointed out in another comment it is not exactly intuitive.

Comment: `float: left` frees `div.add-padding` from having its `width` constrained by the `width` of the `body` element (which is the same as the viewport `width` in this case). Another way to fix it would have been to add `position: absolute`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.  Been banging my head against this same problem for the better part of an hour.  Wish I had bothered to search here first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect problem for Firebug. Right click inspect element, then look for a layout tab. You can trace the css / styles to the parent.

Comment: In this case, I don't think doing that helps particularly. How will it help the questioner to think to apply something like `float: left`?

Comment: @thirtydot  Agreed, I was in fact using firebug, which is how I found the problem in the first place, my real site is not black on blue on red like my demo :)  Obviously I didn't think to add `float:left` or I wouldn't have posted the question.